# Name of a document which provides information about the database logical design?

Tags: database, document, naming

I've been looking around for a while but didn't happen to come across any official name (not even an unofficial one) of a document that summarizes all the tables in the database structure including the field names and a brief description of the purpose of this field within the table.

Does such a document actually have an official or commonly used name? I made one to help myself understand the current database design of a company while designing the new one, and also made one of the new database to help others understand the new database design for the company. If this kind of document has an official name then I could have a look in a certain document to ensure mine meets the requirements for it and making maybe more informative/professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is formally called [Data Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary).
A platform-specific example is Data Description Specifications (DDS) that allow the developer to describe data attributes in file descriptions that are external to the application program that processes the data, in the context of an IBM System